# .htaccess redirection subdirectory to other ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need redirects from a subdirectory to go to the root, example:

**example.com/test/aaa**

**example.com/test/bbb**

We need redirect to **example.com/test**

I have created the next redirect:

```
Redirect 301 example.com/test/aaa example.com/test/
```

And I'm getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error

What is the best solution for this problem? Like example.com/test/# go to example.com/test/

Comment: "I'm getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" - The directive you posted would not cause that error - it wouldn't do anything (since it will never match the requested URL). The redirect-loop error may be due to an earlier (erroneous) redirect that has been cached.

Answer (score 2):

Use `RedirectMatch` with a regex to be able to match both sub-directories in same rule:

```sh
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/test/)(?:aaa|bbb) $1
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: @Manply please let me know how it goes. Also post your full .htaccess in question as I suspect there is some other rule causing `TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`